# ActionBarSherlock ActionBar hidden when themed in Android 2.3

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to personalize UI for my app, but when i change the background of the actionbar, the ActionBar not showing but the split actionbar is ok. In some activity, i see the ActionBar with theme but just menu item (no appicon and title). In Android 4.0 it works very fine, but i've this problem in compatibility mode (Android 2.3)

The code of the theme

```
<style name="aTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.a</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.a</item>
</style>

<!-- style actionbar -->
<style name="ActionBar.a" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/sc4th_actionbartop</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/sc4th_actionbarbot</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/sc4th_actionbartop</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/sc4th_actionbarbot</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Solved !

<style name="aTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
....
<style name="ActionBar.a" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
....

Comment: Thanks, this really helped!  I was also doing   <style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar"> instead of <style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">, and only my background was showing no actionbar content, until I changed it :).  You should add your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved !
Replaced `<style name="ActionBar.a" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">` by `<style name="ActionBar.a" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">`